# "Does not name a type" error even though I declare right before assigning the values

Tags: c++, arrays

I have slimmed my problem down to the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct hello
{
    int array[4];
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 2;
    array[2] = 3;
    array[3] = 4;
};
```

And when I compile this I still get the 'array does not name a type' error, on every line where I assign a value.
AFAIK this error is caused when a variable is nto declared, even though I declare array right above the assignment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assignment **statements** like array[0] = 0; cannot go into the struct definition, the need to go into an executable block of code like a function, a constructor or similar.

```
struct hello
{
    int array[4];
    hello(){
        array[0] = 1;
        array[1] = 2;
        array[2] = 3;
        array[3] = 4;
    }
};
```

Comment: I definitely have objections to having objections to struct with a constructor. In C++, structs should be expected to have constructors sometimes (though there are some features limited to structs/classes that don't have one).

Comment: @Jan, and I would we one to agree. I'm going to delete that "Of course one may have objections to providing a struct with a constructor, but thats another topic."

Answer (score 2):

You should assign the values outside of the struct definition, not inside it.

```
#include <iostream>

struct hello
{
    int array[4];
};

int main()
{
    hello h;
    h.array[0] = 1;
    h.array[1] = 2;
    h.array[2] = 3;
    h.array[3] = 4;

    // do stuff

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like I misunderstood the purpose of a struct

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you cannot initialize the array like this. There are several ways around this:

1) Create a constructor (this will initialize every instance of `hello` with the same values):

```
struct hello {

    int array[4];

    hello() {
        array[0] = 1;
        array[1] = 2;
        array[2] = 3;
        array[3] = 4;
    }
};

hello h;
```

2) Initialize each instance of `hello` with the relevant values (different instances can have different values):

```
struct hello
{
    int array[4];
};

hello h = {{1,2,3,4}};
```

Answer (score 0):

And here another possibility with a static variable, as your intention is not clearly stated:

```
struct hello
{
    static int array[4];
};

int hello::array[4];

int main()
{
    hello::array[0] = 1;

    return 0;
}
```